# Add some word to all or some rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, edit, rows

If I want to add some word before each number of a column, how can I do that.

```
10 s 123

24 c 235

33 s 345

46 s 346

59 s 546

62 c 277
```

I mean : for example I put the word "k" before each number in the first column and get

```
k10 s 123

k24 c 235

k33 s 345

k46 s 346

k59 s 546

k62 c 277
```

Answer (score 5):

- Select All cells that want to change.
- right click and select `Format  cell`.
- In category select `Custom`.
- In Type select `General` and  insert this formol ----> "k"@

Answer (score 2):

Insert a column, for instance a new A column.  Then use this function;

="k"&B1

and copy it down.

Then you can hide the new column A if you need too.

Answer (score 2):

Following Mike's answer, I'd also add another step. Let's imagine you have your data in column A.

- Insert a column with the word you want to add (column B, with k)
- apply the formula (as suggested by Mike) that merges both values in column C (C1=A1+B1)
- Copy down the formula
- Copy the values in column C (already merged)
- Paste special as 'values'
- Remove columns A and B

Hope it helps.

Ofc, if the word you want to add will always be the same, you won't need a column B (thus, C1="k"+A1)

Rgds

Comment: I want to do this for whole of that column by once, but as you and mike said, I should enter the word "k" one by one, and it is hard since the rows are too much.

Comment: This link might help you: 
http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/06/12/excel-mouse-tricks/

Some tricks to copy data. Take a look at _Auto-fill a series of cells with data or formulas by just double clicking_ which might fit your problem.

Comment: Small correction: I had to use the ampersand `&` in order to concatenate strings. Using a plus sign results in a #REF error.

Answer (score 1):

**Save a copy of your spreadsheet first** (just in case).

1. Insert two new columns to the left of the numbered column.
2. Put a k in the first row of the first (new) column.
3. Copy it (the k).
4. Go to the original first column (now the third column) and leave your cursor on the first row that has data.
5. Hit ctrl and down arrow (at the same time) to jump to the bottom of the populated data range for your original first column.
6. Left arrow twice to get to the new first column, the one with a k at the very top.
7. Hit Ctrl-shift-up arrow to go to the first cell with data populated (the original k you put in), highlighting all the cells in-between your starting and ending point.
8. Use paste (ctrl-v, right-click or whatever your preferred method), and it'll fill all those cells with a k.
9. Then use the "Concatenate" formula in the second column. Its two arguments will be the column of Ks (column A, first column) and the column with the numbers in it.
10. This will get you a column with the results of the K column and your numbers.

Hope this helps! The ctrl-shift-arrow and ctrl-arrow shortcuts are amazing for working with large datasets in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert a column left to the column in question(adding column A beside column B).
2. Provide the value you want to append in 1st cell of column A
3. Insert a column right to the column in question ( column C)
4. Add this formula -> =CONCATENATE("A1","B1")
5. Drag it down to apply to all values in column
6. You will find concatenated values in column C

This worked for me !